# Silent, Optional and No account registration dont work

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, virtuemart

I tried to check each of these, and I still see VM registration/login page..I disabled all cache and I have no login modules in the site. You can see it in action: www.webtasty.com ..try to purchase smth and you will be redirected to login page after clicking checkout... How to remove registration/login page? I want to use just paypal payments, so dont need registration. Thank you

ps. it's tpvmcheckoutlogin  module on the page, which displays that login block...

I have latest VM version (and patch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is it set to right now? From the looks of the page it is set to normal now. In any case, changing that setting doesn't remove the registration page, it only changes what is displayed. VM will always want you to fill out the registration form so it knows who is placing an order. Here is what the different options mean -

Normal Registration - checkout page displays a login form and a new user registration form. Users are required to pick a username and password. VM creates a user account.

Optional Registration - checkout page displays a login form and a new user registration form. Users have the option of selecting a username and password to create an account. VM only creates a user account if the option is selected

Silent Registration - checkout page displays a login for and a new user registration form. There are no form fields for username or password, VM assigns those to the user and sends them via email. A user account is created with the assigned credentials.

No regisration - checkout page displays registration form only, no username or password fields, no account login form. VM does not create a user account but still requires the form to be filled out for billing/shipping purposes.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I set it up to No Registration, so it still shows me account login form..

Comment: Are you using a VM theme? It's possible that the theme is overriding the parameters set in the config. If you are using a VM theme. switch back to the default and see if the checkout works as above.

Comment: you're right, I was using simplecheckout theme. Switching to default fixed it, but I lost all the styles and some of functionality...I want to keep my theme, I guess will have manually change a code.. Thanks

Comment: You can probably get away with just deleting the simplecheckout checkout page. If a file is missing from the theme it will just use the default.

Comment: How do I make sure that when with NO REGISTRATION: user comes back, and types the same email address he used before, it does not return error ?

Comment: It shouldn't return an error when a no registration user returns because no Joomla user record exists. When the system checks the email address for a previous entry it only checks the Joomla user table. The only record of the email address for a no registration user will be in the invoice, not the Joomla user table.